# android studio can't connect to debug devices

Tags: android, android-studio

Android Studio can't connect to debug devices.

When I click the debug button, the debug tab shows me

```
Connecting to the target VM, address: 'localhost:8600', transport: 'socket'
```

in variables

When I tried again it told me

```
12:14:44 Error running Android Debugger (8600): Unable to open debugger port : java.io.IOException "handshake failed - connection prematurely closed"
```

and then debug tab show me this

```
 Disconnected from the target VM, address: 'localhost:8600', transport: 'socket'
```

in variables

My Android Studio version is `0.4.4 #AI133-1005886`

This problem has been haunting me for a long time.

i use OS X

Comment: Have you tried checking if the port 8600 on localhost is being listened by another process?

Comment: i check it only studio listening this port

Comment: This question is not offtopic -- it is about Android Studio, an IDE for doing Android development, connecting to a test device while developing and debugging an application.

Comment: need more up-to-date answer to this question ~~~~~~~~~~~

Answer (score 54, accepted):

in android studio:
tools->android->enable adb integration(this should be checked) **uncheck this, then check again.** this solved me this problem. (it restarts the adb integration)

Comment: Worked for me too!

Comment: Worked for me. Great!

Comment: This isn't working for me.
I have uncheck and check again but problem still present.
what are other solution for this problem. I have tried all thing from this post

Comment: Run -> Attach Debugger to Android Process

Answer (score 7):

This is how I solved same issue:

1) I don't think that it is important but I: updated all pending for update ADT stuff. And restarted OS. But I still was unable to debug

2) Next: I launched AS. Opened terminal and ran this:

```
./adb get-state
```

- daemon not running. starting it now on port 5037 *
- daemon started successfully *

As you can see daemon started automatically after I asked for its state. So I did not do nothing more. Just tried to debug and this time debugging worked.

P.S. After I restarted AS debugging continued working. So there was no need in terminal manipulations anymore

Comment: but when i open my terminal and run "adb get-state" it told me : localhost:~ SongMengyu$ adb get-state
device   noting but this  debug does still not work

Comment: In which directory do you run "adb get-state"? My bash does not recognize it.

Comment: @NoniA. /Applications/Android Studio.app/sdk/platform-tools/adb

Comment: Upvoted cause this worked for me as well, but this is mind boggling.  Why does this even happen?  I spent about 2 hours trying to trouble shoot before I found this.  How frustrating...

Answer (score 6):

Well, what it worked for me:
I have change my /etc/hosts file and make sure that those 3 lines are on the bottom of the file:

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
::1             localhost
```

Answer (score 4):

This is how I solved same issue:
(1)remove or disconnect your phone !
(2) connect your phone again!

Answer (score 2):

After failure of all the solutions. I made a work around:

1) Run the app normally. [image]

2) Attach the debugger to android process. [image]

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem just restarting my Android studio

Answer (score 1):

I faced this error too. I had to **disable Instant Run** to get the Debugger working.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using VirtualBox with Androidx86 OS then you need to wake up simulator first: Machine -> ACPI Shutdown (Host+U)

Answer (score 0):

To everyone that hasn't solved this problem yet, `./adb get-state` worked for me.

But, the second time I got this problem, the cause was the wrong item selected in a drop down menu called `Select Run/Debug Configuration` beside the debug button. Select `App` in that menu would solved the problem.
(Refer to answer to this question: [Android Studio Always Disconnect Immediately after beginning "debug"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27905119/android-studio-always-disconnect-immediately-after-beginning-debug))

Answer (score 0):

For me, there was one another instance of DDMS(other than Android studio) was running...I closed that and restarted the Debug ...started working.

Answer (score 0):

If none of the other solutions worked for you (as it didn't for me), I suggest to **try to do a clean reinstall of the Platform tools**.

1 - Start the standalone **SDK Manager**.

From Android Studio: Tools->Android->SDK manager, SDK Tools tab, click start standalone SDK manager.

2 - Close Android Studio.

3 - In **SDK manager**, in the **Tools folder**: check **Android SDK Platform-Tools** and click on the **Delete packages** button in bottom right corner.

4 - In **Explorer**, delete the folder android-sdk-path\platform-tools.

5 - Back in **SDK manager**: re-check **Android SDK Platform-Tools** and click on the **Install packages** button.

Comment: I cannot recommend this answer.  For step 4, I renamed instead of deleting, just in case.  My next attempt to debug my project failed because there was a problem opening the target picker dialog.  I renamed the directory back to the original name, and the target picker problem disappeared.

Answer (score 0):

In a Windows environment, I brought up Taskmgr and it showed many copies of the debugger running. Shutting down Android Studio and restarting it solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was install all new tools:

- LLDB 2.3 (lldb;2.3)
- CMake 3.6.3155560 (cmake;3.6.3155560)
- GPU Debugging tools (extras;android;gapid;3)
- Instant Apps Development SDK (extras;google;instantapps)

Hope it helps anyone.

Answer (score 0):

in my case i edited etc/hosts's everything goes wrong.

clear files /etc/hosts debug work.

Answer (score -2):

I also got this error, and the other answers didn't work for me.

I fixed it by removing

`multiDexEnabled true`

from my debug configuration in the build.gradle file.