# Android Studio always disconnect immediately after beginning "debug"

Tags: android, debugging, android-studio

Every time I try to debug any project with Android Studio, the app does not start, and immediately the console gives following message:

> Connected to the target VM, address: 'localhost:8603', transport: 'socket'
>   Test running startedDisconnected from the target VM, address: 'localhost:8603', transport: 'socket'

I generally try to debug on my **HTC Desire Z with Android 2.3.3** device and I remember that with Eclipse IDE the "debugging" works without any issues.

Answer (score 3):

I finally solved it!

The problem was that at the left of start and debug button, the configuration menu was set to test. Just put it on App and now it works.

Comment: What ? I have same problem but what you mean by configurationmenu ?

Comment: Upper, in the ide, there is the "green arrow button" to run the project, immediatly on the left there a drop down menu.

Comment: Ok nevermind i solved my issue it was exception i did not see in logcat , after exception disconnection occured