# Android App crashes while trying to attach debugger

Tags: android, android-studio, crash

Some of, just some of, my apps crash while I try to attach Android Studio debugger, then I receive this error :

```
Disconnected from the target VM, address: 'localhost:8602', transport: 'socket'
```

I tried restarting Windows & Android Studio & My Nexus, nothing works.

I am using latest version Android SDK, Build Tools,...

Part of log after this crash :

```
01-16 09:08:26.967 18208-18213/? A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422] Runtime aborting...
01-16 09:08:26.967 18208-18213/? A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422] Aborting thread:
01-16 09:08:26.967 18208-18213/? A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422] "Jit thread pool worker thread 0" prio=5 tid=2 WaitingForDebuggerSend (still starting up)
01-16 09:08:26.967 18208-18213/? A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   | group="" sCount=0 dsCount=0 obj=0x0 self=0xec00d000
01-16 09:08:26.967 18208-18213/? A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   | sysTid=18213 nice=9 cgrp=default sched=0/0 handle=0xf2aa5920
01-16 09:08:26.967 18208-18213/? A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   | state=R schedstat=( 2419166052 199636564 1513 ) utm=213 stm=28 core=5 HZ=100
01-16 09:08:26.967 18208-18213/? A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   | stack=0xf29a7000-0xf29a9000 stackSize=1022KB
01-16 09:08:26.967 18208-18213/? A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   | held mutexes= "abort lock"
```

Comment: Have you try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27905119/android-studio-always-disconnect-immediately-after-beginning-debug

Comment: @DharmaKshetri I am not in Test Mode

Answer (score 6):

I had the exact same problem in Android Studio 3.0 on Mac. The solution came from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37423225/android-studio-debugger-application-crashes-with-interruptedexception/45124105#45124105), basically you need to disable Instant Run (eventhough I haven't use it):

Under Mac OS X:

1. Android Studio
2. Preferences
3. Build, Execution, Deployment
4. InstantRun
5. uncheck "Enable Instant Run to hot swap ...".

There is a "Having trouble with Instant Run?" message displayed in the settings panel. I clicked on "Re-enable and activate extra logging", reproduced the crash, and then immediately reported using the "Help - Report Instant Run Issue..." option as they requested.

Comment: Started happening after my device updated from Marshmallow to Nougat. This resolved the issue... thanks a ton!

Answer (score 0):

I solve same kind problem few month ago, by using this, please try this one time:

**Go to**

> 1. tools
> 2. android
> 3. enable adb integration, this must be check when you are in debugging. try to uncheck and again checked.
> 4. finally restart android studio or upluged then pluged moibile device.

Hope it works.

Comment: same here :'(
Does anyone have a solution to this?

Comment: Worked for me, I tried without restart and unplug my device but It wasn't effective.

Answer (score 0):

This may sound really dumb, but after hours of trying around and restarting everything I could, what really solved the issue was.....

1. Uninstall the application.
2. Clean project (Build -> Clean Project)
3. Install

That's it!!

Hope this helps.

Comment: this didn't help