# Android Studio Debugger Port Error - "handshake failed - connection prematurely closed"

Tags: android-studio

When I try to attach the Android Studio Debugger to a process, I get the following error:

```
Error running Android Debugger (8603):
Unable to open debugger port (localhost:8603): java.io.IOException "handshake failed - connection prematurally closed"
```

Kudos to whoever spelled prematurely that way.
Anyway, how do I get around this problem?

I'm using Android Studio 1.2.2 on Ubuntu. 
[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22024041/3817111) did not help.

Comment: Don't you mean, "Kudos to whomever"?

Comment: the quick answer would be file -> Invalidate Caches/Restart, and then Start debug again (Alt + Shift + D)

Answer (score 41):

The best and one solution for me was just to restart Android Studio.

Before I tried to restart adb server from command prompt or disable and enable adb integration from tools->Android->Check/Unchek the line, unplug and plug device , but nothing helped.

Comment: In my case, on windows I restarted android studio then everything was ok.

Comment: No-one is listening on that port, restarted but still getting the same error msg.

Answer (score 32):

For me these didnt work: Restart Android Studio,adb kill start server, restart phone.

Worked for me: Tools->Android->Disable and Enabled ADB Integration.

Comment: This menu is not in Android Studio 3.1, best option is to restart Android Studio.

Answer (score 16):

On Windows, restarting Android Studio didn't work. I instead killed the "adb.exe" process then retried.

Comment: this answer is a best solution

Comment: This worked for me by typing:
taskkill /im adb.exe /f
in to a command prompt

Answer (score 5):

I didn't need to restart my device, only restarting android studio fixed it ( clean your project if needed).

If doesn't work then restart your device.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe you should consider retaining only **one device or a emulator**, because Android Studio or Intellij IDEA only accept one device or emulator when debugging. It works well for me. I hope this can help.

Comment: Nice!  The problem was based on having two emulators open at once.  However, it doesn't proactively answer the question.

Comment: I've same issue. My personal device connected pc and i have an emulator opened. I could not debug with both of them. After i close emulator started working. thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Restarting the ADB server worked for me:

```
$ adb kill-server

$ adb start-server
* daemon not running. starting it now at tcp:5037 *
* daemon started successfully *

$ adb devices 
List of devices attached 
ce0217127216c0220c  device
```

Answer (score 2):

I had to restart both my android device and android studio. That seemed to work for me.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, often the reason is bad USB cable. Just replace another, better USB cable will work.

Answer (score 0):

It shows that your previous debbugger was not closed. You should click stop (red button) to stop your attach previously, and rerun your debbugger. It would attach again