# Disconnected from the target VM, address: 'localhost:8613', transport: 'socket' for Android Studios version 2.2.2

Tags: android, sockets, adb, android-virtual-device

I have started using Android Studio versions 2.2.2 recently. But after I update my Android Studio to version 2.2.2, Im getting an error like this when i Debug the app:-

**Connected to the target VM, address: 'localhost:8614', transport: 'socket'**

**Disconnected from the target VM, address: 'localhost:8614', transport: 'socket'**

The AVD is getting launched, But this error is coming when I open the app after unlocking the screen. I have searched in Stackoverflow website for some fix. But none of them is working for me.

I tried once by uninstalling and re-installing the studio. After that it was working fine for sometime. Now again I am facing this issue. Can someone please help me on this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [android studio can't connect to debug devices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21745143/android-studio-cant-connect-to-debug-devices)

Comment: How did you solve this problem. I'm also getting equivalent https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48313766/android-studio-getting-error-as-disconnected-from-the-target-vm

Answer (score 0):

Open the command prompt of window and just use the command given below

adb kill-server

adb strat-server