# How to solve debug problem in android studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio

When i debug my project I faced the below error :

```
《Disconnected from the target VM, adress:'localhost:8600', transport: 'socket'》
```

Please help me resolve it. Any pointers would be helpful.

Comment: Reconnect your usb cable and device again and make sure that u r using a stable usb cable.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [android studio can't connect to debug devices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21745143/android-studio-cant-connect-to-debug-devices)

Comment: I have tried it with another cable but no change

Answer (score 0):

you can restart your ADB like below in you CMD in windows:

1. `adb kill-server`
2. `adb start-server`

or you can connect your device via WIFI, it's better:

1. connect you device
2. in cmd: `adb tcpip 5555`
3. and find your phone ip and run cmd code: `adb connect ip:5555`

and finally pull your cable and your connected via WIFI

Comment: I try what you have told me but it doesn't  work . Please if you other solution tell me.

Comment: if you are connecting your phone so the problem is your phone maybe. some times phone cant be on usb debuging mode  so if this is not this case it about you pc that maybe you have disabled or you do set a permission for something or about wrong config.

Comment: At the begining it worked for me , but after adding some xml codes its becomes like this . There is alot of warnings on the xml,I think it is the problem ,but  my teacher on the youtube have same warnings but it works for him. What i have to do now?please help me.

Comment: Hey dude,I think I got it, this is not your ADB problem bot it just my attitude that in your project is a setting that makes a conflict with android studio and your ADB,Gradle cant build  your project and other project that setting is in your gradle scripts . 
1: Is this your project or import it to your android studio? if it is the probability of this above thing is low. 
2: Is this project an open source project that you are using? if it is the probability of this above thing is very high.

Comment: No, i programed it.i did not import aproject